Concurrent round robin implementation fails
I'm trying to write an in-memory implementation of the load balancer that will have a get() method returning the instances in a round-robin pattern, I need it to run properly in a concurrent environment, however, even after setting up the locks and synchronization with thread-safe data structures, I cannot make the test pass.
My LoadBalancer:
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class LoadBalancer1 {

    private final List<String> instanceList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 10;
    private final LoadBalancerStrategy strategy;
    private static final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private static final ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock readLock = lock.readLock();
    private static final ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock writeLock = lock.writeLock();

    public LoadBalancer1(LoadBalancerStrategy strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    public boolean register(String instance) {
        writeLock.lock();
        try {
            if (size() == MAX_SIZE) {
                return false;
            }
            if (instanceList.contains(instance)) {
                return false;
            }
            instanceList.add(instance);
            return true;
        } finally {
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public String get() {
        readLock.lock();
        try {
            return this.strategy.get(this.instanceList);
        }finally {
            readLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        readLock.lock();
        try {
            return this.instanceList.size();
        } finally {
            readLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

interface LoadBalancerStrategy {
    String get(List<String> instances);
}

class RandomStrategy implements LoadBalancerStrategy {
    @Override
    public String get(List<String> instances) {
        if (instances.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return instances.get(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(instances.size()));
    }
}

class RoundRobinStrategy implements LoadBalancerStrategy {

    private final AtomicInteger currentIndex = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Override
    public String get(List<String> instances) {  // Synchronize access
        if (instances.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        int index = currentIndex.getAndUpdate(i -> (i + 1) % instances.size());
        return instances.get(index);
    }
}

My test:
@RepeatedTest(100)
    void should_keep_round_robin_pattern_in_concurrent_environment() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        // given
        loadBalancerRoundRobin.register("1");
        loadBalancerRoundRobin.register("2");
        loadBalancerRoundRobin.register("3");
        Queue<Future<String>> objects = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(30);

        int threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        var executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(threads);
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                Future<String> submit = executorService.submit(() -> loadBalancerRoundRobin.get());
                objects.add(submit);
            }
        } finally {
            executorService.shutdown();
            executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size() - 3; i += 3) {
            assertEquals("1", objects.remove().get());
            assertEquals("2", objects.remove().get());
            assertEquals("3", objects.remove().get());
        }
    }

For each test I create new objects:
@BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        randomStrategy = new RandomStrategy();
        roundRobin = new RoundRobinStrategy();
        loadBalancerRandomStrategy = new LoadBalancer1(randomStrategy);
        loadBalancerRoundRobin = new LoadBalancer1(roundRobin);
    }

I'm slowly running out of ideas on finding out where is the issue, I belive that currentIndex is getting modified in unsafe manner idk how to find the reason. Or maybe there is an issue with size()  method but since it's locked idk what else I could do. If anyone could explain what happens I would be extremely grateful.

What exactly is your problem? Which assert fails?

Why do you expect that specific order of execution?

I expect the objects queue to contain the instances returned in a round-robin pattern, and the pattern is broken so one of the asserts is failing when the test is repeated multiple times.
When multiple threads are trying to retrieve the instance, I expect each subsequent request to return '1' (first) '2' (second) '3' (third) '1' (fourth)
and due to some issue with the code this pattern is broken and for example '1' '3' '2' sequence occurs

The threads from the executor are unordered, so their arrival times are non-deterministic and thus the output must be. Further, by not using a fair lock, it allows lock barging for higher throughput whereas you are expecting a FIFO lock. Yet since you use a CAS loop on an atomic counter, that too is not fair and depends on the hardware deciding the winning order. The output goal is truly a sequential problem so that is best handled by a single thread, where you show a ping pong across threads by queuing the tasks instead of the threads, e.g. CompletableFuture and thenRun predecessor chain.

@BenManes Wow, that Comment would make a terrific Answer here.

@BasilBourque haha, my drive by comments take 30 seconds at most, so I don't feel like they should be answers as I didn't put any effort into it. If it is correct then I'm happy for the author to answer their own question, merely thanking me for the hint. When I do write an answer I want to be more thoughtful than "oh yeah, I did that dumbly too so here's my screw ups, might be yours".
